# Unexpected results when trying to append values to a vector: Mac OS

Tags: r, vector, append

I have the code below where I am trying to append an observation to nobs for each iteration. I have tried multiple things: predefining the nobs vector, predefining results as a data frame, changing c(nobs, nobs2) to data.frame(nobs, nobs2).

What I receive:

```
Warning messages:
1: In cbind(id, nobs) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
2: In cbind(id, nobs) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

If I do not call the function, and do each line separately, I receive the following results:

```
id nobs
[1,] 1  ?   
[2,] 2  117 
[3,] 3  1041
[4,] 1  243
```

I am expecting an output of:

```
id nobs
1  243
2  1041
3  117
```

Code:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:3) {
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
        dat <- data.frame()
            for (i in id) {
                dat <- data.frame(read.csv(files_list[i]))
                    dat_cln<- dat[complete.cases(dat), ]
                      nobs2 <- nrow(dat_cln)
                        nobs <- c(nobs, nobs2)
        results <- cbind(id, nobs)
        }
}
```

Comment: Try putting this line `results <- cbind(id, nobs)` outside the `for` loop, and you also have not returned a result from the function, so don't use `result <-` when you do that

Comment: `sapply(list.files(directory, pattern = '.csv', full.names = TRUE), function(x) nrow(read.csv(x)))`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I moved the the results outside of the loop and removed the "results" bucket, but I still get the below. Why am I not able to read in the first row of code in order? Thank you again for all of your help. I have literally spent day on this code trying everything I can think of and find online.                                                                  id nobs
[1,] 1  ?   
[2,] 2  117 
[3,] 3  1041
[4,] 1  243 
Warning message:
In cbind(id, nobs) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: figured it out! Just needed to define nobs as an empty vector. Thank you again for all of your help!